# IntelliJ IDEA can't recognize method recursion in a forEach call

Tags: java, recursion, intellij-idea, java-8

Consider the following code I attached as an image:

[image]

The code does an infinite loop but that's not the point. The point is that if I make the recursion inside a `for` loop then IDEA can show that at the left with a sign.

If I make the recursion inside a `forEach` lambda expression then there are no sign.

It would be much comfortable if it can be shown in both cases.
Is it a bug, or is there any reason for that?

Comment: There is no direct recursion in the second case. IntelliJ doesn't know what the `forEach` method on the object that `IntStream.range(0, 10)` returns is going to do with the lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly noted by @Jesper in his comment, not every lambda is called synchronously from the function to which it is passed as a parameter. Imagine that the function used in the example was `invokeLater` and not `forEach`.

Since IntelliJ is not aware of the semantics of specific library functions that take lambdas as parameters, it does not highlight recursive calls in any lambdas.